# Added mass and damping of a vertical cylinder

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, boundary-conditions

why the velocity potential can be written as this term:

$\Phi(r,\theta ,z,t)=\bar{h}Re[-i\sigma \phi (r,z)\bar{\xi}_3 e^{-i\sigma t}]$

where $\sigma$ is the angular frequency, $\bar{\xi}_3$ the heave amplitude. All space variables are non-dimensionalized by water depth. a represents the radius to water-depth
ratio; d the bottom clearance to water-depth ratio.

Besides, how to get this boundary condition

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\bigg|_{z=d}=1 \quad 0\le r\le a$

[image]

Reference: Yeung, R. W. (1981). Added mass and damping of a vertical cylinder in finite-depth waters. Applied Ocean Research, 3(3), 119-133.